# Visual Studio automatically include cmath?

Tags: compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013, cmath

I'm a beginner in C+=, just wrote my Hello World today.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
double x = 6.25;
x = sqrt(x);
std::cout << x;
return 0;
}
```

This worked in Visual Studio, no error message, while adding:

```
#include <cmath>
```

worked fine as well.

But with a GCC compiler online the previous code returns with

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:12: error: 'sqrt' was
not declared in this scope x = sqrt(x);
                                     ^
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no auto include behaviour.. by including `<iostream>` you are indirectly including `<cmath>`.

It's just the way that Microsoft implemented the C++ standard library, they wanted to use some `<cmath>` functions in  so they needed to include it in the header file.

I recommend you read this [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/54150/).

Comment: Thanks, but what if I just want to use the C++ standard library without their implements? Can I disable it?